# How to make a Model with a Many-to-Many relationship as Categories (i.e) rock ,Country, Blues, and Pop

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Album(models.Model):
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_photo = models.FileField()
    author = models.ForeignKey (User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='album', default='1')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post:detail',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.creator + ' - ' + self.album_name

class Song(models.Model):
    Album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.song_name
```

Edit:
I would like to have another model to categorize all of my albums in which would  take multiple categories. The categories would be pre specified choices that would make the queries more robust and easier to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is define Category as a Model with a Many-to-Many relationship with Album. That way, you can do things like: `Album.objects.filter(category__name='country')` or you could take an instance of Category and do `category.album_set.all()`

Try this above your Album model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    desc = models.TextField()
```

Then add to your Album model:

```
category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

Comment: Great! The relationship worked. How would i make it be one of the pre made categories?